# How to label unlabeled text data

Tags: machine-learning, label, lda

I have collected some social media comments regarding food reviews and I am planning to perform aspect base sentiment analysis. As an initial process I want to label those unlabeled data into some predefined topics such as price, quality, taste etc.
As I am new to machine learning not sure whether I can proceed labeling without having labeled test data. Appreciate your help

I tried LDA topic modeling but felt that is not the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Aspect based sentiment analysis is a complex problem in NLP. It is actually quite trickier than standard sentiment analysis.

You can go with labelling, of course, but if you have not an initial plan, it will likely be a waste of time. You need to make sure you are doing the labelling in the right way and have at least some certainty that your model will learn something from not many examples (assuming you are the only one labelling them).

I suggest that you read some papers on aspect based sentiment analysis. Generally, it is really useful to provide additional information about the aspect other than the aspect itself. For example, if you have the sentence:

"The flight was nice, but the passengers next to me were very loud and annoying".

Let's say that you only care about the aspect "flight". You can pass to the model the following training example:

((Encoding(sentence), encoding(aspect)), 1)

1 here means that there is a positive sentiment towards the aspect. This is fine if you have shorter sentences assuming that you will use a transformer as backbone, because the encoding/embedding of the aspect "flight" is contextual, and it will contain information about the surrounding words (or, more accurately, it will be encoded in a smart way, so that the encoding is appropriate wrt the context).

But imagine if you have a huge article and you care about the sentiment of an aspect that is mentioned only once. Then passing the encoding of the article and the encoding of the tiny aspect MIGHT confuse the model. It would be appropriate, as you correctly thought, to provide more information about the aspect, such as what is its topic, or even parts of the text (sentences) which talk about that aspect, so the model has even more information.

It all boils down to what kind of task you need to do.

You can check this library: https://github.com/yangheng95/PyABSA , although it is not very well documented and is a little hard to get used to it.

If you have any questions, please let me know down in the comments.